# HttpServletRequest login method not working

Tags: jsf, authentication, glassfish

Hy everybody,
I want to implement a programmatic authentication with jsf.
I already configured glassfish authentication realm, and setted in web.xml:

```
  <login-config>
<auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
<realm-name>authJdbcRealm</realm-name>
<form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/home.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/loginError.xhtml</form-error-page>
</form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

home.xhtml has a form that access a managed bean with following method as action attribute:

```
public String login()
{
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
      {
            request.login(customer.getUsername(),customer.getPassword());

        }
        catch (ServletException e) 
        {
            errorMessage(e.toString(),e.getMessage());
        } 
            return null;}
```

getPassword() returns plain text (not the sha256-digest, that should be performed by the auth realm). Although a j_security_check form works without problem, with the programmatic way I always get a ServeletException, with this StackTrace:

```
INFO: JACC Policy Provider: Failed Permission Check,
context(TravelDream/TravelDreamWeb_war)-
permission(("javax.security.auth.AuthPermission" "createLoginContext.jdbcRealm"))
WARNING: WEB9102: Web Login Failed: com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.login.common.LoginException:
Login failed: access denied ("javax.security.auth.AuthPermission" "createLoginContext.jdbcRealm")
```

Any ideas about what's wrong?

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1:

**Disable** the Security Manager option from the admin console, then Save and restart server.

You can find this option in *Configurations -> server-config -> Security*

#### Option 2:

If security manager is required to be **enabled**. Grant permission to the application by adding a new codeBase in `server.policy`. i.e.:

```
grant codeBase "file:[domain_dir]/applications/[application_name]-" {

  permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "createLoginContext.jdbcRealm";  
  permission javax.security.auth.AuthPermission "doAsPrivileged";

};
```

N.B:

- Do not delete anything from this file, just add the permissions shown above
- `server.policy` is found in `[domain_dir]/config/`
- `[domain_dir]` and `[application_name]` is to be substituted by your own domain directory name  and application name
- **More information can be found in the application server documentation** [(PDF)Glassfish server application development guide](https://glassfish.java.net/docs/4.0/administration-guide.pdf)

Comment: Please elaborate why it is such a good idea to disable a security manager. Does it have adverse effects?

Comment: @Artjom B By disabling the security manager, the aspect which may be affected is security of application and possibly that of the server's. Normally, for an application to access resources such as database or files, it would need permission to do. No security manager, means that the application is allowed to access such resources(which introduces the possibility of maliciousness). Obviously, if the server is hosting untrusted(or unknown) applications, it would not be a good idea to disable it, but on other the side - no security manager, leads to improved performance.

Comment: Thanks, maybe you can add this explanation to your answer?